# A While loop inside a cursor's while loop - SQL

Tags: sql

```
declare @i int
declare @skool float

declare schoolCursor cursor for  
select distinct choice from tempstuas

open schoolCursor
fetch next from schoolCursor into @skool
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
        while @i < 20
            begin
                update top(1) tempstuas set cnt=@i where cnt = '' and cat = 1 and choice=@skool
                update top(1) tempstuas set cnt=@i where cnt = '' and cat = 2 and choice=@skool
                update top(1) tempstuas set cnt=@i where cnt = '' and cat=3 and choice=@skool

                set @i = @i + 1
            end
        fetch next from schoolCursor 
end
close schoolCursor
deallocate schoolCursor
```

This is basically going through a cursor that returns an individual location number. The location number is stored as a variable from the cursor which I need to use inside a while loop that iterates through a specific amount of times (20). What I am returned is just the cursor going on for the whole list of location numbers but does not iterate through the while loop with the update statements.

Comment: 1). `SET @i = 1` (or 0, or whatever you need) immediately before the `WHILE` statement? 2). Find a way to do this without using Cursors and While Loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursors and while loops are generally the wrong way to solve a problem, I don't have time right now to figure out what exatly you are doing to suggest a set-based solution but seriously you need to start thinking in sets and stop thinking loops.

However your problem is that @i is null, null is not <20.

see this test of my theory

```
declare @i int

if @i<20 print'hi'
else print 'bye'
```

Comment: HLGEM is spot on. Initialize the i variable. However you should try and move away from the row by agonizing row approach (RBAR). Cursor are very often a performance killer.

Comment: Initializing the i, i=0 was the solution to get this to iterate through. Is there any recommendations for sets theory or links? Thanks for your help and quick response.

Comment: here's a starting place: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them